# Can't assign result of table valued function to table variable

Tags: sql-server

I have this function:

```
Create function [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String nvarchar(max)
)
returns @SplittedValues table
(
    Id nvarchar(50) primary key
)
```

In a stored procedure, I am trying to take the result of this functions invocation and insert it into a table variable:

```
DECLARE @SplittedValues table
(
    [Id] nvarchar(50) primary key
);
INSERT INTO @SplittedValues([Id])
VALUES (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split](@Commands);
```

I get

> Incorrect Syntax near "SELECT"

DB version is SQl Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
INSERT INTO @SplittedValues([Id])
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split](@Commands)
```

Syntax `insert into table_name (columns_list) values (values_list)` should be used when you have some finite values list written in your query.

But when you're inserting from resultset obtained from some select, it shold be `insert into table_name (columns_list) select values from another_table`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading. If you really wanted to use (scalar!) subselects in the `INSERT .. VALUES()` clause, you'd have to add additional parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO @SplittedValues([Id])
VALUES ((SELECT * FROM ...));
```

That would be the *"correct"* syntax. But in your case, that doesn't make sense anyway. You want to copy the outcome of the `SELECT` into the `@SplittedValues` table as a whole. So, try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO @SplittedValues([Id])
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split](@Commands);
```